# Im trying to create an image while using a list full of RGB values

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, colors

I am trying to create an image using a list full of RGB values where every one of them is a pixel ,I am also using numpy so i can edit the list by transforming it to a multidimensional array ;However, when i transform the list to an array , the tuples that contain the RGB values becomes a list that contains RGB values and when i finish editing the array and re transform it to a list the RGB values are in a list instead of a tuple and thus cannot be used as pixels.Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
liste=[(134,234,200),(234,0,255)]
new_array = numpy.array(liste)
final_list=new_array.tolist()
im = Image.new("RGB",(10,10))
im.putdata(final_list)
im.show()
```

the final list will be like that :`[[134, 234, 200], [234, 0, 255]]`
meanwhile the result i need is :`[(134,234,200),(234,0,255)]` (or the liste)

Comment: because it gave me a type error when i used the array i created in numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html?list-comprehensions#list-comprehensions) to convert a list of lists into a list of tuples, like:

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]
>>> l = [tuple(i) for i in l]
>>> l
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster with `map`

```
from time import clock

spin = 200000

t0 = clock()
for c in range(spin):
    li = [[134, 234, 200], [234, 0, 255], [122,12,45], [210,50,87], [3,150,250],
          [100,200,0], [230,44,78], [35,78,40], [122,124,231], [251,98,13]]
    li = [tuple(e) for e in li]
t1 = clock() - t0
print("%.3f" % t1,"  li = [tuple(e) for e in li]   bgporter")



t0 = clock()
for i in range(spin):
    li = [[134, 234, 200], [234, 0, 255], [122,12,45], [210,50,87], [3,150,250],
          [100,200,0], [230,44,78], [35,78,40], [122,124,231], [251,98,13]]
    li = list(map(tuple,li))
t2 = clock() - t0
print("%.3f" % t2,"  li = list(map(tuple,li))      eyquem")

print("   %.3f / %.3f =  %d %%" % (t2,t1,(100*t2/t1)))
```

result:

```
1.150   li = [tuple(e) for e in li]   bgporter
0.938   li = list(map(tuple,li))      eyquem
   0.938 / 1.150 =  81 %
```